# Saving IDA Graph to PDF format?

Tags: ida, static-analysis

I want to save flow/call graph of IDA into a pdf format so that I could view it in my android. How can I do that?

I know IDA can generate a flow chart (gdl file) and call chart (gdl file). But my question is, how do I convert those file format into pdf so that I could view the pdf on my android and iPad? I have no experience with those file formats before.

Thank you.